# MUI MenuItem + Link doesn't follow "to"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use MUI to create a `MenuItem` + `Link` with a nested `Typography` component that will navigate to the link on click.

Currently I am using the [Responsive App Bar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#app-bar-with-responsive-menu) here as a template.

Here is the code I currently have for the open/close menu + states, as well as the component I've defined for making links in the hamburger menu.

```
const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState(null);
const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState(null);

const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
  setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
};
const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
  setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
};

const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
  setAnchorElNav(null);
};
const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
  setAnchorElUser(null);
};

const HamburgerMenuLink = ({ text, href }) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem component={Link} to={href} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
      <Typography textAlign="center">{text}</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

Here is where the `Menu` + `HamburgerMenuLink` is implemented:

```
<Menu
  id="menu-appbar"
  anchorEl={anchorElNav}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left",
  }}
  keepMounted
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "left",
  }}
  open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
  onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
  sx={{
    display: { xs: "block", md: "none" },
  }}
>
  <HamburgerMenuLink text="Beers" href="/beer" />
  <HamburgerMenuLink text="My Beers" href="/beer/me" />
  <HamburgerMenuLink text="New Beer" href="/beer/new" />
</Menu>
```

I have tried the following:

1. wrapping the `HamburgerMenuLink` in a `Link` component
2. adding the `component={Link}` prop to the nested `Typography` instead of `MenuItem`

Neither of these resulted in navigating to the route in the `to` prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `component` prop does not expect a actual **Component**, it expects a **elementType**. See [the MenuItem props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/#props).

So what you can do is pass a `"a"` to the `component` prop and simply use the `href` as you would on a `a` tag.

```js
const HamburgerMenuLink = ({ text, href }) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem component={"a"} href={href} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
      <Typography textAlign="center">{text}</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you for explaining the `elementType` too